# ROS_DISTRO was set to 'fuerte' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions

Tags: ros, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_DISTRO was set to 'fuerte' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
I HAVE INSTALLED FUERTE AND HYDRO . HOW TO SET ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES FOR HYDRO?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135351/ros_distro-was-set-to-%27fuerte%27-before.-please-make-sure-that-the-environment-does-not-mix-paths-from-different-distributions./) by [anand.m91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12771/anand.m91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-03**:
Please don't use caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By sourcing correct setup.bash files.

This is just a warning. If you are consciously switching between fuerte and hydro you should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0